# How to change first day of the week to Monday on a DateItem's popup picker in SmartGWT?

Tags: gwt, date, calendar, smartgwt

I noticed that [DateChooser](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/DateChooser.html) has the method `setFirstDayOfWeek(int)`, but since DateChooser does not extend FormItem, I cannot use it in my DynamicForm instead of [DateItem](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/DateItem.html).

So, my question is, how do I make the calendar component in the popup to show Monday as the first day of the week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Smart GWT, but assuming the DateChooser item is based on native GWT date widgets, you can change its behavior by setting the locale of your application.  Adding the following two lines to my [Application name].gwt.xml file (just below the "inherits" lines) changed these widgets to display Sunday-Saturday.  I believe the default locale is "en" which was using a Monday-Sunday week (though it seems the opposite may be the case for you).

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_US"/>
<set-property name="locale" value="en_US"/>
```

Comment: That's it. I was actually using Finnish "fi" locale, but the firstDayOfWeek attribute was incorrectly set to 0 instead of 1 in the  properties file that contains the translations. SmartGwtMessages_fi.properties or something.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use a widget which is not a subclass of `FormItem` as in your case the `DateChooser` you can use a `CanvasItem` which can be added to your dynamicForm and add the `DateChooser` as a member of this `CanvasItem`.

Comment: That seems like a viable workaround. However, I'm still looking for a way to do this with the actual DateItem.